# compounding / while loops

Tags: c, compound-assignment

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int days, hours, mins;
  float a, b, c, total, temp, tempA, tempB;

  a = 3.56;
  b = 12.50;
  c = 9.23;
  total = a+b+c;
  days = total / 24;

  temp = total/24 - days;

  hours = temp * 24;

  tempA = temp*24 - hours;

  mins = tempA*60;

  while (hours >= 24)
    {
      hours= hours-24;
      days +=1;
    }
  while  ( mins >= 60)
    {
      mins=mins-60;
      hours +=1;
    }
  printf("days:%d\n", days);
  printf("hours:%d\n", hours);
  printf("mins:%d\n", mins);


  return 0;
}
```

I wanted to convert decimal hours to real time and I can do it fine but I wanted to increase days hours if the hours is beyond 24 and if mins is beyond 60mins. 
the while loop does subtract and it does print out the new value but the hours / days aren't getting compounded. 
It was 1 day 1 hour 77mins
I wanted it to read 1 day 2 hours 17mins
but I'm getting 1 day 1 hour 17 mins.

Comment: You may want to check your math by hand; `3.56+12.5+9.23 == 25.29`, which is `1.29` hours longer than one day.

Comment: hmm Yea I think I did my math wrong

Comment: Any particular reason why you are avoiding a mod operator `%` ? Your implementation would have become a lot more simpler with it.

Comment: haven't gotten that far in the c book so thats why I didn't use it doing examples from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your program I'm getting:

```
days:1
hours:1
mins:17
```

and that's what I expect considering that total should be 25.29.

Answer (score 2):

Using the modulus operator will make your life much easier: it will give the remainder of a division.

```
int total;

/* a=; b=; c=; assignments */

total = a+b+c;
mins = total % 60;
total /= 60;
hours = total % 24;
days = total / 24;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler implementation of what you are trying to do:

```
void TimeFix(int &days, int &hours, int &mins)
{
    hours += mins/60;
    mins %= 60;
    days += hours/24;
    hours %= 24;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, your math is just a little off.  `(= (+ 3.56 12.50 9.23) 25.29)`, not 26.29.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a while loop you can use division:

```
days += hours / 24
hours %= 24
```

Also, do your minutes-to-hours stuff before your hours-to-days stuff.